Reading multiple serial ports in Python - how would a simplified, more elegant way to loop?
I am reading data from multiple CDC devices (for testing purposes just two).
I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to loop over initializing and reading the CDC ports.
I guess the loops can be solved in a much more elegant way.
import serial
import serial.tools.list_ports

ports = serial.tools.list_ports.comports()

for port, desc, hwid in sorted(ports):
   print("{}: {} [{}]".format(port, desc, hwid ))

serialPort = {}

for i in range(len(ports)):
    try:
        serialPort[i] = serial.Serial(ports[i].device)
    except ValueError:
        print('Port Configuration problem')
    except serial.SerialException:
        print('Port not found or cannot be configured')

while True :

    for i in range(len(serialPort)):
        serialChar = serialPort[i].read(1)

        try:
            # Convert byte to string (character)
            serialChar = serialChar.decode("ascii")
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            # Don't raise error if byte is not ASCII
            pass
        else:
            # Print the received byte in Python terminal
            print(serialChar, end="")
            if serialChar == 'z':
                print('\n', end="")


Your last for loop won't always work if any of the ports in the second loop can't be opened.

I think one thread per serial port would be cleaner and more readily scaled out for more devices. They could each take a semaphore when they wanted to write to the Terminal so the output isn't jumbled together.

Are you using Python on Windows or a "Unix"-ish O/S. As J_H suggested, on a Posix O/S you have the option of using select() which can be used to wait until one or more of the serial ports have data to be read.

pythonic

a more elegant way to loop

Yes.
The OP code sort of takes a Fortran / C approach,
incrementing an index i to access elements of a container.
Modern languages such as Python favor this iteration idiom:
    for x in xs:
        print(x)  # or otherwise do stuff with x

In your case we might have for port in serial_ports:
unicode
The OP code seems to assume that almost all characters read
shall have the high bit off.
If an interesting number of multi-byte unicode glyphs
arrive over the serial port, the OP output will be unintelligible.
You might consider at least displaying a "?" question-mark
for each ASCII decode failure.
blocking I/O
The .read(1) can potentially block for a long, long time.
If you have N ports, and even one of them is idle,
your loop will find that port and get stuck on it,
ignoring the data arriving on the other N - 1 ports.
You want to use non-blocking I/O, so the request for 1
byte can potentially result in an immediate read of 0 bytes.
Or else you want to probe each port before reading it.
If the port is not ready, if there's no data waiting,
then don't attempt to read it.
In an embedded context, that's probably about as fancy
as you can get. On a Posix host, including e.g. Raspberry Pi's,
you can select(). Some operating systems let you use more
sophisticated primitives such as kqueue or epoll().
burning a core
while True:

As written, your code keeps the CPU as busy as possible.
Please sleep() for at least a millisecond each time through the loop.
Consider doing adaptive sleeps, so after a period of idleness
you might sleep for 50 msec at a time, until activity resumes.
